# angular material: md-select not working with "controller as" syntax?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

All I did was modify their official Async Search demo (it fits my use case) to make use of "controller as", and getting weird behaviour as a result. [Codepen is here](http://codepen.io/spectrus/pen/dMjxeB). Am I missing anything?

Here's the relevant bits of code from the above link:

**JS:**

```
angular.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache'])
.controller('SelectAsyncController', function($timeout, $scope) {
  var vm = this;

  vm.user = null;
  vm.users = null;

  vm.loadUsers = function() {
    return $timeout(function() {
      vm.users =  vm.users  || [
        { id: 1, name: 'Scooby Doo' },
        { id: 2, name: 'Shaggy Rodgers' },
        { id: 3, name: 'Fred Jones' }
      ];
    }, 650);
  };
});
```

**Markup:**

```
<div ng-controller="SelectAsyncController as vm" layout="column" ng-app="MyApp">
    <md-select placeholder="Assign to user" 
               ng-model="vm.user" 
               md-on-open="vm.loadUsers()">
      <md-option ng-value="vm.user" 
                 ng-repeat="user in vm.users">{{user.name}}</md-option>
    </md-select>
    <p>Assigned to: {{ vm.user ? vm.user.name : 'No one yet' }}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change ng-value to "user".

```
<md-option ng-value="user" ng-repeat="user in vm.users">{{user.name}}</md-option>
```

Here is the working [Codepen](http://codepen.io/woofy/pen/BKPXeW).

Comment: Was almost there! Спасибище! :)